# What is the blur effect 3D Touch Peek uses? (Simulating it gives a different one)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, 3dtouch, uivisualeffectview

I am simulating 3D Touch Peek using UILongPressGestureRecognizer in case the device do not support 3D Touch. Everything is going fine so far. However, when I add the popup, the blur effect is quite different from the one with the real 3D Touch. Here are the screenshots for better understanding.

[Real 3D Touch Peek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjheB.jpg)

[Simulated 3D Touch with blurEffectView.alpha = 0.94 and effect: .Dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ3Z3.jpg)

This is the closest I could get to the real 3D Touch blur effect but it still seems very different. If I reduce the alpha, the blurEffect will look more like a fog than really a blur like in the Real 3D Touch. Do you guys have any ideas on how to solve this problem?